# Where can I find API Documentation containing headers classes and methods in MFC VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to find [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) like documentation for MFC C++ classes. Where we can get clear information on headers associated,data members and methods for MFC Library. MSDN doesn't look helpful since it doesn't contain information on which header need to be in linked.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I'm confused, it's says the header right there under requirements. Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za93adby.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I was expecting a Java like structuring. I found the header in the MSDN page @dutt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the header under Requirements if you scroll down a bit, for example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za93adby.aspx

Posting this as an answer as well so you can accept and people can spend their time on other questions.